# HtmlAgilityPack work with structure

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-agility-pack

I'm starting with some crawler in C# and I heard that HtmlAgilityPack  is best solution for this.

I can't find valid example of usage so maybe someone here will help me with my issue.

In one class I'm using method to get part of code I want. For example ul with class "testable ul"

```
public static string GetElement(string url, string element, string type, string name)
{
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
    string rate = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//"+ element +"[@"+ type +"='"+ name +"']").OuterHtml;
    return rate;
}
```

so I am running

```
string content = SiteMethods.GetElement(startPage, "ul", "class", "testable ul");
```

now there is a part where I am doing some background work but in the end I'm loading that string again to HtmlAgality:

```
            HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
            html.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
            html.LoadHtml(content);
            HtmlNode document = html.DocumentNode;
```

And here I have a problem. 
The structure inside content string is like that:

```
<ul class="testable ul">
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.veryimportant.link">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="http://image.so.important/">
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <span class="name">
                    NAME
                </span>
                <span class="price">10</span>
                <span class="price2">8</span>
                <span class="grade">C</span>
            </div>
            <p class="tips">tips</p>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.veryimportant.link/2">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="http://image.so.important/2">
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <span class="name">
                    NAME2
                </span>
                <span class="price">3</span>
                <span class="price2">4</span>
                <span class="grade">A</span>
            </div>
            <p class="tips">tips2</p>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So the questions are:

1. How to get every `<li>` to diffrent object? For further actions.
2. is it possible in one simple command to get links `http://www.veryimportant.link` and `http://www.veryimportant.link/2` or for example images `http://image.so.important/` and `http://image.so.important/2` ? How to get them?
3. How to get NAME and NAME2 in list?
4. Is it possible to map the whole struct of html to list?

Please, with some examples the rest of learning will be really easy.

Comment: Use XPath. Everything will be easy.

Comment: I dont know how to even start that here. Thats why I asked about example.